# Coefficients of a sine series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, applications

I am reading a paper on fluid mechanics- https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1954.0197 . Here, the author takes the sum of sines $\overline{WT}=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty\Sigma_{m=1}^\infty\alpha_{nm}\sin{\frac{n\pi z}{d}}\sin{\frac{m\pi z}{d}}$, and equates it to $\overline{WT}=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty(\alpha_{n}\sin^2{\frac{n\pi z}{d}}+\gamma_{n}\sin{\frac{n\pi z}{d}}\sin{\frac{(n-1)\pi z}{d}})$. He then relates the coefficients as shown in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92lef.jpg). I am not able to understand how these series were equated and how the values of the coefficients were obtained. Can someone please explain the math behind it?

Comment: The product-to-sum identities give an idea for why the coefficients are of the form $\alpha_{i(n-i)} - \alpha_{i(i+n)} - \alpha_{(i+n)i}$, but actually showing you can regroup the sum into that form looks tricky.